# Is there a parallel implementation of Poly1305?

Tags: parallel-processing, cryptography, mbedtls

In Poly1305's features (https://cr.yp.to/mac.html) it is listed that:

> (**Parallelizability and incrementality**) Poly1305-AES can take advantage of additional hardware to reduce the
> latency for long messages, and can be recomputed at low cost for a
> small modification of a long message.

Looking through the code in the mbedTLS implementation on Github for example I could not find if or how this feature is used. Is there some well known implementation that utilizes this parallelizability, and if so how does it do it roughly?

Comment: Mbed TLS is designed for embedded systems with small code size. It's not the place to look for advanced features designed to optimize speed for specific workloads, or for taking advantage of high-end hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly described, it uses Parallel Horner to evaluate Poly1305 instead of standard Horner.

One implementation that uses this is OpenSSL with vectorization activated, i.e., AVX etc.